# Dash black after unlocking in 21.10

Tags: 21.10, dash-to-dock, gnome-dash

After upgrading to 21.10, I find that when I unlock the screen after it has been dormant for a while, the dash is black. The only way I've found to get it back is to log out and back in again.

I didn't have this issue in 21.04, so how do I go about troubleshooting it?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.10 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/07/25/ubuntu-20-10-groovy-gorilla-end-of-life-reached-on-july-22-2021/ https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: Should have typed 21, not 20. Have edited.